# Problems with showing user profiles like /users/2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a user model with routes using `resources :users`but am having trouble showing individual user profiles through links.  The index page below shows all of the users in a list:

**users/index.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'All drivers') %>
<h1>All drivers</h1>

<ul class="center hero-unit col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div class="user-name">
    <li><%= link_to user.name, user %></li>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

But when I click on a user on the index page (say user 3), it sends me to /users/3 .  This page gives me this error:

`No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` but the link is going to /users/3 and is passing parameters {"id"=>"3"}. So how can the id be nil? I don't understand how to get these links working.

**users.controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  #add before action for index
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]

    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Thank you for signing up, welcome to ensage!"
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
          render 'edit'
      end
    end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'shop_sessions/new'

  get 'shops/new'

  get 'cars/new'

  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'shophome' => 'static_pages#shop_home', as:"shop_home"
  get 'shop', to: 'static_pages#shop_home', as: 'shop_root'
  get 'shops', to: 'shops#index', as: 'shop_index'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get 'shopsignup' => 'shops#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  get    'shoplogin'   => 'shop_sessions#new', as: 'shop_login'
  post   'shoplogin'   => 'shop_sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  delete 'shoplogout'  => 'shop_sessions#destroy', as: 'shop_logout'

  resources :users
  resources :shops
  resources :cars,  only: [:create, :destroy, :edit]
end
```

**users/show.html.erb**

```
    <div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @user.cars.any? %>
      <h3>Cars (<%= @user.cars.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="cars">
        <%= render @cars %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**rake routes**

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
shop_sessions_new GET    /shop_sessions/new(.:format) shop_sessions#new
        shops_new GET    /shops/new(.:format)         shops#new
         cars_new GET    /cars/new(.:format)          cars#new
     sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
        users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
             root GET    /                            static_pages#home
        shop_home GET    /shophome(.:format)          static_pages#shop_home
        shop_root GET    /shop(.:format)              static_pages#shop_home
       shop_index GET    /shops(.:format)             shops#index
             help GET    /help(.:format)              static_pages#help
            about GET    /about(.:format)             static_pages#about
          contact GET    /contact(.:format)           static_pages#contact
           signup GET    /signup(.:format)            users#new
       shopsignup GET    /shopsignup(.:format)        shops#new
            login GET    /login(.:format)             sessions#new
                  POST   /login(.:format)             sessions#create
       shop_login GET    /shoplogin(.:format)         shop_sessions#new
        shoplogin POST   /shoplogin(.:format)         shop_sessions#create
           logout DELETE /logout(.:format)            sessions#destroy
      shop_logout DELETE /shoplogout(.:format)        shop_sessions#destroy
            users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
                  PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
            shops GET    /shops(.:format)             shops#index
                  POST   /shops(.:format)             shops#create
         new_shop GET    /shops/new(.:format)         shops#new
        edit_shop GET    /shops/:id/edit(.:format)    shops#edit
             shop GET    /shops/:id(.:format)         shops#show
                  PATCH  /shops/:id(.:format)         shops#update
                  PUT    /shops/:id(.:format)         shops#update
                  DELETE /shops/:id(.:format)         shops#destroy
             cars POST   /cars(.:format)              cars#create
         edit_car GET    /cars/:id/edit(.:format)     cars#edit
              car DELETE /cars/:id(.:format)          cars#destroy
```

Comment: Provide `rake routes` output too.

Comment: I suspect issues with `correct_user` or your `root` path in routes.rb. Can you comment out the `before_action` from your controller and `root [...]` from your routes.rb and see if the issue persists?

Comment: In the show view you are referencing the link to edit the user.  That link may have a problem.  Post the source for `users/show.html.erb` if you can.

Comment: @maxd rake routes have been added above

Comment: @Swards I added users/show.html.erb above

Comment: hover over the link and check what the link is. also, inspect the link in UI & check.

Comment: @prasad.surase the link goes to /users/1 with the number changing based on ID. Inspecting shows `<a href="/users/2">Andrew Hausdorf</a>`

Comment: @swards I took the edit user part out of show.html.erb, shown above.  Now I can go to users/1 and it shows, but other links aren't working and I get this error: `'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.`

Comment: @Swards several other of the user links are working. I imagine there is something wrong with users/2 and a few others. just not sure how to avoid this nil property in the future

Comment: That's probably because you are rendering a nil object, is it possible one of the @cars is nil?  Try to inspect that list